# Does YARD have implicit dependencies?

Tags: ruby, runtime-error, bundler, yard

In short, I have the following problem with 
    [my Ruby Gem project](https://github.com/reitzig/texlogparser):

- `rake doc` runs locally without issue. (Ruby 2.3.1)
- `rake doc` errors out in the CI agent. (Ruby 2.5)
- `bundle exec rake doc` errors out locally with the same error. (Ruby 2.3.1)

How can that be?

Now for the details. The relevant part of my 
    [`gemspec`](https://github.com/reitzig/texlogparser/blob/master/texlogparser.gemspec) 
is:

```
s.add_development_dependency 'github-markup', '~> 2.0'
s.add_development_dependency 'rake', '~> 12.3'
s.add_development_dependency 'redcarpet', '~> 3.4'
s.add_development_dependency 'yard', '~> 0.9'

s.metadata['yard.run'] = 'yri' # use "yard" to build full HTML docs.
```

I install the dependencies with `bundle install`, as usual.

And my 
    [`Rakefile`](https://github.com/reitzig/texlogparser/blob/master/Rakefile):

```
require 'yard'

desc 'Build documentation'
YARD::Rake::YardocTask.new do |t|
    t.name = 'doc'
    t.options = %w(--markup-provider=redcarpet --markup=markdown --main=README.md)
end
```

The 
    [errors I get](https://circleci.com/gh/reitzig/texlogparser/48) 
are:

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
/usr/local/bundle/gems/yard-0.9.12/lib/yard/logging.rb:44:in `initialize'
<snip>
/usr/local/bundle/gems/yard-0.9.12/lib/yard/rake/yardoc_task.rb:74:in `block in define'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:104:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:104:in `<main>'

Caused by:
NameError: undefined method `<<' for class `YARD::Logger'
Did you mean?  <
/usr/local/bundle/gems/yard-0.9.12/lib/yard/logging.rb:136:in `<class:Logger>'
<snip>
/usr/local/bundle/gems/yard-0.9.12/lib/yard/cli/yardoc.rb:245:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/yard-0.9.12/lib/yard/rake/yardoc_task.rb:74:in `block in define'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:104:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:104:in `<main>'
```

Find the full output of `bundle exec rake doc --trace` 
    [here](https://gist.github.com/reitzig/967e1b42255676a486003f6784ce674c#file-error-with-trace).

This looks awfully buggy to me.

Locally, I have 
    [many more gems installed](https://gist.github.com/reitzig/967e1b42255676a486003f6784ce674c#file-gem-list) 
than those required by this project, so my suspicion is that that combination/configuration of Rake with YARD might depend on some other gem implicitly. Short of going through them one by one, then two by two, etc., is there a way to diagnose this issue? Are there any canonical gotchas I might have fallen into?

Comment: Seems like it’s your code relies on something that is not supported by YARD, but supported by some other gem in your system-wide installation (rails?). Try to rerun the task with `--trace` please.

Comment: @mudasobwa No Rails anywhere, to my knowledge. See [here](https://gist.github.com/reitzig/967e1b42255676a486003f6784ce674c) for a full `gem list` and the output of `bundle exec race doc --trace`. I don't see any of my code in there (it shouldn't be run, or is it?). Does YARD have features it doesn't provide itself? That sounds off.

Comment: The only "special" features I'm aware of are those given to `t.options`. Removing that line does not help.

Comment: A few documentation commits later, it works again. So apparently is was something in the docs themselves that triggered bad code in YARD?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not a fortuneteller and I don’t know :) It’s good everything went OK in the end.

Comment: @mudasobwa Sure! Just wanted to leave that comment for future reference. I'll see if I find time to try and bisect the changeset to find out what caused the behaviour. Thanks for your time!